# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HeatmapOverlay' + angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I installed the following :

```
"@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^8.1.0",
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"leaflet-geosearch": "^3.0.6",
"leaflet-heatmap": "^1.0.0",
"leaflet-timedimension": "^1.1.1",
"leaflet.heat": "https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/tarball/gh-pages",
"@types/leaflet": "^1.5.17",
```

in index.html I added the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C3J1.jpg)

and add the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmDZl.jpg)

in map.service.ts I wrote the the following code:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js';

heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(this.cfg);
```

When run the project is working but give me the following error in console and when build the project give me build filed:

> ERROR in src/app/shared/services/map.service.ts:39:24 - error TS2304:
> Cannot find name 'HeatmapOverlay'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that angular doesn't recognize the HeatmapOverlay what you can do is one of the following:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js';

heatmapLayer = new (window as any).HeatmapOverlay(this.cfg);
```

or declare it as a type which I would recommend

```
declare var HeatmapOverlay:any;
```